# How to Kill buffer in emacs without answering confirmation?

Tags: emacs

How to kill the buffer in emacs without being questioned.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will kill the current visible buffer without confirmation unless the buffer has been modified. In this last case, you have to answer y/n.

```
(global-set-key [(control x) (k)] 'kill-this-buffer)
```

Comment: This has interesting side effects when used within emacsclient. Of course there are reasons for errors but I want to have a constant experience: @Noufal's solution is better.

Comment: progo, what side effects?

Comment: Per function's documentation, it can only be reliably called from menu bar, else it may randomly and silently do nothing. I observed this, and had to move to `(kill-buffer (current-buffer))` as shown below.

Comment: I am still this message for `helm` buffers: `Buffer *helm for files* HAS BEEN EDITED.  Kill? (y or n)`

Answer (score 6):

I use this

```
(defun volatile-kill-buffer ()
   "Kill current buffer unconditionally."
   (interactive)
   (let ((buffer-modified-p nil))
     (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'volatile-kill-buffer)     ;; Unconditionally kill unmodified buffers.
```

It will kill the buffer unless it's modified.

Comment: (let ((buffer-modified-p nil)) has no effect. It's a function. You can't bind it with "let".

Comment: Good point. I picked this up from someplace and didn't really bother editing it.

Comment: How can I do this for `(kill-matching-buffers "*helm")`

Answer (score 6):

OK, I've done some poking around in the Emacs manual and found a working solution (as of Emacs 23.4.1). It's almost identical to Noufal's solution:

```
(defun kill-this-buffer-volatile ()
    "Kill current buffer, even if it has been modified."
    (interactive)
    (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
    (kill-this-buffer))
```

I've renamed the function a bit to make it a closer cousin to `kill-this-buffer`.

Apparently, the EmacsWiki has a page on this topic at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillBufferUnconditionally (modified in 2007), but the code is just a copy of Noufal's.

Answer (score 4):

Use `(kill-current-buffer)` instead of `(kill-this-buffer)` if you want to bind it to some key. See the docs for `(kill-this-buffer)`

> ...
>
> This command can be reliably invoked only from the menu bar,
>   otherwise it could decide to silently do nothing.

and `(kill-current-buffer)`

> ...
>
> This is like ‘kill-this-buffer’, but it doesn’t have to be invoked
>   via the menu bar, and pays no attention to the menu-bar’s frame.

So I would put the following in my `init.el`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'kill-current-buffer)
```

This works at least in emacs 26.1.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following piece of code -- unlike Noufal's solution of ignoring the buffer being modified or not, this will save the buffer and then kill it.  It also deletes the window which makes a difference when you have several sub-windows showing -- by default it will remove the window instead of switching to some other buffer.  (To use this conveniently, you need to bind some key to it, of course.)

```
;; Kill the current buffer immediatly, saving it if needed.
(defvar kill-save-buffer-delete-windows t
  "*Delete windows when `kill-save-buffer' is used.
If this is non-nil, then `kill-save-buffer' will also delete the corresponding
windows.  This is inverted by `kill-save-buffer' when called with a prefix.")
(defun kill-save-buffer (arg)
  "Save the current buffer (if needed) and then kill it.
Also, delete its windows according to `kill-save-buffer-delete-windows'.
A prefix argument ARG reverses this behavior."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((del kill-save-buffer-delete-windows))
    (when arg (setq del (not del)))
    (when (and (buffer-file-name) (not (file-directory-p (buffer-file-name))))
      (save-buffer))
    (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
      (when del (delete-windows-on buf))
      (kill-buffer buf))))
```

Comment: don't forget `(global-set-key (kbd "C-q") kill-save-buffer')` to bind this to C-q (or else)

Comment: Yeah, I did say "you need to bind some key to it"; but using `C-q` is a bad idea since it's a very common binding in Emacs....

Comment: Is this code still working for you? For me it saves the buffer and kill it but do not close the emacs window anymore.

Comment: I still use the almost the same code, I just added `(buffer-modified-p)` to the condition for saving the buffer.

Comment: Ok for me this code below save and quit the buffer but does not close the windows (emacs stays open). Also, could you add the `(buffer-modified-p)` code to your post?